# any other way to send the responce to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting response from other python application, now i am using this way to display the data into jsp.

```
public static String preparelistrpmesponse(String str){

          if(str.startsWith("1"))
              return prepareErrorResponse(str);

          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
          String[] data;
          try{
              data = str.split(",");
              response.append("<table cellspacing='0'><th><b>RPM</b></th><th></th>");

              response.append("<tr><td align='left' width='300px'>");             
              response.append("<select id='rpmOption' multiple>");
              for (String tdata : data) {
                  response.append("<option value='"+tdata+"'>" +tdata+ "</option>");
              }
              response.append("</select>");
              response.append("</td>");

              response.append("<td align='left' width='300px'>");
              response.append("<select id='rpmOptionSelected' name='rpmOptionSelected' multiple>");
              response.append("</select>");
              response.append("</td></tr>");

              response.append("<tr>");
              response.append("<td align='left' width='300px'> <input onclick='add()' type='button' value='Add >>' /> </td>");
              response.append("<td align='left' width='300px'> <input onclick='delet()' type='button' value='<< Delete' /> </td>");
              response.append("</tr>");

              response.append("<tr><td align='left'>"); 
              response.append("Move To : <input type='radio' name='foption' value='1' checked>PRE-APPROVAL<input type='radio' name='foption' value='2'>LIVE-GOLD");
              response.append("</td><td></td></tr>");
              response.append("</table><br />");
              response.append("<input type='submit' onclick='execPushtotr()' value='submit' />");

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return response+"";

    }
```

any other way to display dynamic data.

i need to send the response to jsp then need to display.

can any one help on this.

Comment: I want way are you receiving the response from Phython? How do you intend to 'send' the data to the JSP? Please show the complete code.

Comment: pls view this link :http://snipt.org/Ahfhb3

Answer (score 0):

To use JSPs and Servlets:

1. You need to run your code in a Servlet Container, such as Tomcat, Jetty, Resin, etc.
2. Your code needs to comply with the Servlet API

Currently your code example is a simple static method with no indication of how it is run.

Answer (score 0):

Well beside Prabhakaran's remark, I think it would be better to to put your own html code directly in the JSP and use a jsp expression[`<%= ...%>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm) to inject the previous response's content or -better- to create a [new tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm) (or several ones).

BTW, are you looking for advises, as I suppose or are you facing a precise problem?

Comment: i want to use jsp instead of appending in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a JSP rather than a servlet (btw JSPs are effectively servlets) then you should parse the response that you receive from the Phyton script, extract the data, encapsulate it in an object and pass that to a JSP page which uses taglibs to extract the data from the object. For example if the data is in a table format you can use `<c:forEach/>`.